# conflicts: 1 reduce/reduce, error: expected ',' or '}' before '.' token

Tags: parsing, bison, reduce-reduce-conflict

Problem Part of grammar:

```
tracelevel
: TRACELEVEL LPAREN IDENT RPAREN         { $$ = makeFuncTraceLevel($3);  }
| TRACELEVEL error                       { $$ = 0; error("Expected 'log(<EV_TRACE>)'");  }
;

category
: CATEGORY LPAREN IDENT RPAREN           { $$ = makeFuncCategory($3);  }
| TRACELEVEL error                       { $$ = 0; error("Expected 'log(<EV_CATE>)'");  }  
;
```

Warning that I am getting:

```
edc.y: conflicts: 1 reduce/reduce
edc.y:169.7-93: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: category: TRACELEVEL error
```

In the category token I tried to replaced "TRACELEVEL error" with "CATEGORY error"

After that I am getting this error:

```
y.tab.c:135: error: expected ',' or '}' before '.' token
recipe for target 'y.tab.o' failed
```

the file y.tab.c just contains these kind of things:

```
CATEGORY = 279,
EVTIDINCL = 280,
MIBINCL = 281,
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for what makes a good question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is not enough information here to suggest a solution, since the reduce-reduce conflict must be triggered by some *use* of the two non-terminals. Please attempt to create a [mcve] (which is a complete runnable program of minimum size, *not* an excerpt of the program which exhibits a problem). The compilation error at the end of your question is mostly likely the result of some typo you introduced during the edit; again, there is not nearly enough information to respond.